# Iterating a for loop?

Tags: python, iteration

Is it possible in Python to iterate a for loop and what does a code for such construction look like?

To be clear, here is what I mean by iterating a for loop:

```
for i in range(100):
     for j in range(100):
         for k in range(100):
...
             for n in range(100):
                  print(i+j+k+...+n)
```

And here is a specific example I would like to see simplified:

```
data0=numpy.random.normal(0,1,100)
data1=numpy.random.normal(0,1,100)
data2=numpy.random.normal(0,1,100)
A=numpy.zeros(100*100*100)
for i in range(len(data0)):
    for j in range(len(data1)):
        for k in range(len(data2)):
             A[i*len(data0)*len(data1)+j*len(data0)+k]=data[i]+data[j]+data[k]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: have you tried this by yourself ?

Comment: you probably need `itertools.product`

Comment: Have you tried a recursive approach?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Dole your post isn’t the clearest. I find it a bit hard to understand. Note the wrong answer, you may want to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is you're asking for an optimization known as [Loop Unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling). To do this, you need to look at optimizations (perhaps deterministically) from the lowest nested level upwards.

In this case, it's not possible. In general, this loop amounts to setting each element of the tensor `A[i,j,k] = d0[i]+d1[j]+d2[k];` in a sense, this is a one-to-many operation.

If, however, there were regular patterns in the data vectors `data0`, `data1`, and `data2`, you could take advantage of a few heuristics that could help. In this case, though, you've set them to be random vectors, so no underlying assumptions about organization or structure are useful.

Comment: I am not asking for optimization, but a way to make the code more compact and have a user set amount of the for loops in series. Preferably pythonic way.

Comment: Frankly, the nested loops _are_ pythonic. These are particularly necessary as a clearer way of navigating each dimension of the tensor itself.

Comment: Perhaps, although when there are 6 loops in a row it starts to look a bit messy. However, there is still problem defining arbitrary amount of loops. My plan is to edit the question to make it clearer when time permits.